# Convert a php array to something similar in C# and send it via cURL/HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, php, arrays, json, curl

Hi I am fairly new to C# and this is my first question posted here. I am accustomed to php, but need a C# solution. I am trying to build an array similar to the following in C# that will later be converted to JSON and sent via cURL or I guess HttpWebRequest in c#. What is the best solution?

```
 $member_data = array(
  "email" => $email,
  "fields" => array(
    "first_name" => $first_name,
    "last_name" => $last_name
  ),
  "group_ids" => $groups
);
```

This is the cURL I am converting to HttpWebRequest

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $public_api_key . ":" . $private_api_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($member_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($member_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$head = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add what c# code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with HttpClient and converted the collected data directly to a JSON string instead of messing with the array conversion and I was able to get it to work.

```
public static void addSubscriber(String firstName, String lastName, String Email)
        {
            var addMemberUrl = baseUrl + "/members/add";
            int groupId = 1927094;
            string jsonString = "{\"email\":\"" + Email + "\",\"fields\":{\"first_name\":\"" + firstName + "\",\"last_name\":\"" + lastName + "\"},\"group_ids\":[" + groupId + "]}";

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
                try
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", publicApiKey, privateApiKey))));
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Version", "1");
                    StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
                    stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    var response = httpClient.PostAsync(addMemberUrl, stringContent);

                    var StatusText = response.Result;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(StatusText);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }
        }
```